# How to truly separate concerns for hiearchical data using the Data Mapper pattern

Tags: php, zend-framework2, datamapper

I am quite new to the [Data Mapper pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). I guess I am missing something, because, for me, it fails for everything more complicated than the most basic examples.

Let's say I have a simple website composed of pages:

```
class Page {
    private $id     = null;
    private $parent = null;
    private $title  = null;
    private $body   = null;

    public function setId($id)              { $this->id     = (int) $id; }
    public function setParent(Page $parent) { $this->parent = $parent;   }
    public function setTitle($title)        { $this->title  = $title;    }
    public function setBody($body)          { $this->body   = $body;     }

    public function getId()     { return $this->id;     }
    public function getParent() { return $this->parent; }
    public function getTitle()  { return $this->title;  }
    public function getBody()   { return $this->body;   }
}
```

Now I want to instantiate **Page 7** that is deep in the tree:

- Page 1

  - Page 2

    - Page 3

      - Page 4

        - Page 5

          - Page 6

            - Page 7

Using the Data Mapper pattern I would use the following mapper class:

```
class PageMapper {
    public function fetch($id) {
        //...
        $data = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = ?", $id);
        $page = new Page();
        $page->setId($data['id']);
        $page->setTitle($data['title']);
        $page->setBody($data['body']);
        if ($data['parent_id'] !== null) {
            $page->setParent(
                $this->fetch($data['parent_id']);
            );
        }
    }

    public function save(Page $page) {
        //...
    }
 }
```

The problem is obvious: **I must instantiate all parents all the way up to the root Page.**

Now imagine a Page would need to know about its children. That would mean, if I would want to instantiate the root Page, I would have to load **the entire tree**.

A solution could be that the parent/children would be loaded only on demand, but that would mean that the domain objects would have to know about the mapper in order to pull data from it... and the separation would be gone.

The domain models (instances of the **Page** class) should know nothing about the Data Mapper layer (separation), but still be able to perform those tasks (retrieving parent/children).

Is separation of concerns achievable in these conditions? If yes, how?

Comment: On a side-note: for deep trees, the Nested-Sets-Model is much more efficient in terms of reading power. While inserting and updating nodes may be very big tasks, the speed of reading complete and partial trees is unmatched by other models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Doctrine, a orm framework which implements the data mapper pattern:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

The problem with your approach is not the instantiation of the entire tree (children), but
the amount of queries it would use.

Look at the doctrine approach, there you would have a children property, which is loaded at once with one query.

I would also never recommend to implement a self-made solution for an orm.

A possible solution would be also to use a Closure:

```
class Page {
//...
    public function setParents(Closure $pages)
    {
        $this->parents = $pages;
    } 
}

class PagesMapper {

public function fetch() {
//fetch the page ...
$parents = function($parent) use($id, $db) {
        parents = $db->query(/* select parent... */);
        $pages = array();
        foreach($parents as $parent) {
            $page = new Page(); 
            $page->id = $parent->id;
            //...
            $pages[] = $page;
        }
        return $pages;
    };
    $page->setParents($parents);
    return $page;
}
}
```

So the page domain would have no knowledge of the persistance layer.

Comment: `Closure` is the answer I was looking for. It enables the domain model (Page) to fetch its parent without knowing how it is done, by calling the closure and reading its return value. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you're building trees using Doctrine 2, I would suggest looking at the `tree` extension in `DoctrineExtensions` (https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md)